# Странный id для div

Tags: javascript, html

Как это работает?

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div id=res></div>
  <script>
    res.innerText = "Hello, World!"
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPD.** Мне казалось, что `id` может быть только строкой: `id="res"` и обращаться к элементу с этим можно только так: `document.getElementById("res")`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Вопрос в другом, а почему оно не должно работать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский человек не сказал что это не работает. Он попросил описать почему и как. Ну мне так кажется.

Comment: @Sergalas ну пишет странный id, значит считает что он неправильный, а значит как с неправильным id может код работать? Мне показалась такая логика)

Comment: В HTML закрывать не обязательно все теги, имена тегов и атрибутов можно писать в любом регистре, кавычки не обязательны.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне кажеться тут не только и не сколько сам див интересует сколько селектор ну или лучше сказать в связке почему не закрыт селектор и почему такой селектор.

Comment: @Sergalas, что значит _не закрыт селектор_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доступ к html элементам можно [получить напрямую по их id](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom#document-getelementbyid-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-id), т.е. использовать форму как в Вашем примере: `res.innerText`, где res - id для данного div. Это поведение определено в стандарте и необходимо прежде всего для обратной совместимости.

Comment: Почему innerText, а не innerHTML?

Comment: @SergeyPestov, а почему обязательно innerHTML?

Comment: @SergeyPestov "Нестандартное свойство innerText" https://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties

Answer (score 1):

> Как это работает?

Ужасно это работает.

Во-первых, попадание id в глобальное пространство имён, насколько я представляю, является нестандартным (хотя, может уже и стандартизировали). Некоторое время назад в FF оно не работало, сейчас уже нормально.

Во-вторых, `innerText` - это жуть. Кроссбраузерность у него весьма сомнительная, оно является нестандартным и в FF появилось только в 46 версии. А в хроме, где оно есть изначально, даже на присваивание оно медленнее стандартного `textContent` *в десятки* раз.

> ```
> res.innerText = "Hello, World!"
> ```

```
document.getElementById("res").textContent = "Hello, World!";
```